# How do i validate an image for byte-size in Content Editor?

Tags: content-editor, validation

I would like to Validate the Image Field say i shouldn't allow the image more than 1 MB. How do I do that in content editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Cassidy explained, you can only achieve this via the implementation of a custom validation rule. Please see below the code for the custom validation.

```
[Serializable]
public class ImageWeightDynamicValidator : StandardValidator
{
    public int Weight;

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "ImageWeightDynamicValidator";
        }
    }
    protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
    {
        ItemUri = ItemUri;
        var field = GetField();
        if (Parameters.ContainsKey("Weight"))
        {
            Weight = MainUtil.GetInt(Parameters["Weight"], 0);
        }

        var str = field.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return ValidatorResult.Valid;
        }

        if (string.CompareOrdinal(str, "<image />").Equals(0))
        {
            return ValidatorResult.Valid;
        }

        var database = Factory.GetDatabase(ItemUri.DatabaseName);

        Assert.IsNotNull(database, ItemUri.DatabaseName);
        var attribute = new XmlValue(str, "image").GetAttribute("mediaid");

        MediaItem item = database.GetItem(attribute);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute))
        {
            item = Context.Database.Items[$"/sitecore/media library/{str}", LanguageManager.GetLanguage(ItemUri.Language.Name, Context.Database)];

            if (item == null)
            {
                return ValidatorResult.Valid;
            }
        }

        if (item == null)
            return ValidatorResult.Valid;

        var size = item.Size;

        var mediaSizeKb = ConvertBytesToKilobytes(size);

        if (mediaSizeKb > Weight)
        {
            Text = Translate.Text("The image referenced in the Image field \"{0}\" is too big. Max size is \"{1}\" kB", field.DisplayName, Weight.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            return GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.FatalError);
        }

        return ValidatorResult.Valid;
    }

    private static double ConvertBytesToKilobytes(long bytes)
    {
        return (double)bytes / 1024;
    }

    protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
    {
        return GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Warning);
    }

    private ValidatorResult GetResult(string text, params string[] arguments)
    {
        Text = GetText(text, arguments);
        return GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.Error);
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info));

        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    protected ImageWeightDynamicValidator(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Once the code has been set into the solution, you need to create the validation rule item.

1. Navigate to the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Rules/`
2. Create a Validation Rule Item (Right-click -> Insert -> Validation Rule).
3. Fill in the item fields as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Note that you only need to change the `Type` to match your Namespace and Assembly name and also the `Weight` in the Parameter fields. Right now it is set to 1. 1 is in `KB`.

4. Assign the validation rule to your field in the template. You can read the link provided by **Mark Cassidy** in his answer or this [one](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-sitecore-field-validators/). This will help on how to set the validation on the field.

Answer (score 7):

## The setting

Well there isn't really a built in validator for this; [although you could build one](http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field-validator-in-twenty-minutes).

But you can - generally - restrict the size of media in your solution. It is controlled via this setting:

```
<setting name="Media.MaxSizeInDatabase" value="500MB" />
```

Setting it to 1MB would restrict your content authors from uploading large media.

## The alternative

Rather than restricting media like this, a better option (in my opinion) is to make sure all your images are web-optimised when Sitecore sends them to the client.

There are several solutions for this; my preference would be [Dianoga - An automatic image optimizer for the Sitecore media library](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga).

Comment: Hi Mark , Thanks for your answer.Is there any way to validate a specific template ?I need it it in only one template not the whole site

Comment: Unfortunately not. Not without some custom coding. The setting I mention here, is global.